# Error This repository moved. Please use the new location

Tags: git

I am receiving this `'This repository moved. Please use the new location'`
when I use `git push`

this appears after I am changing my user name on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this to update your repo's address in your local repository. Replace `new_username` and `repository_name` as necessary.

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:new_username/repository_name.git`

Comment: Or just `git remote set-url origin [updated link url https://........git]`. In my case I moved it to my clients account, but have access as a user.